# JavaScript, Finding Child DIV by custom DATA ID

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am trying to find a child DIV inside his parent using custom DATA-ID attr **ive already set**, and after found that specific child , removing it. 
I have made my code work, but im wondering if there is a better way of doing it, better method?

lets say im trying to find child with DATA-ID of = 2:

HTML

```
    <div class="parent-div">
       <div class="child-item" data-id="1"> SomeContent </div>
       <div class="child-item" data-id="2"> SomeContent </div>
       <div class="child-item" data-id="3"> SomeContent </div>
    </div>
```

JS

```
    removeChild(dataID) {
       const parentContainer = document.querySelector('.parent-div');
       const children = [...parentContainer.querySelectorAll('.child-item')];

       children.forEach(child => {
          child.dataset.id === dataID ? child.remove() : 0;
       })
   };

   removeChild(2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Find the child directly by using `Element.querySelector()` with an [attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector#Find_a_specific_element_with_specific_values_of_an_attribute), and remove it:

```js
function removeChild(dataID) {
  const child = document.querySelector(`[data-id='${dataID}']`);

  if(child) child.remove();
};

removeChild(2);
```

```html
<div class="parent-div">
  <div class="child-item" data-id="1"> SomeContent </div>
  <div class="child-item" data-id="2"> SomeContent </div>
  <div class="child-item" data-id="3"> SomeContent </div>
</div>
```

If you can have multiple items with the same attribute, use `Document.querySelectorAll()`, and then iterate the results with forEach, and remove the items:

```js
function removeChild(dataID) {
  const children = document.querySelectorAll(`[data-id='${dataID}']`);

  children.forEach(el => el.remove());
};

removeChild(2);
```

```html
<div class="parent-div">
  <div class="child-item" data-id="1"> SomeContent </div>
  <div class="child-item" data-id="2"> SomeContent </div>
  <div class="child-item" data-id="2"> SomeContent </div>
  <div class="child-item" data-id="2"> SomeContent </div>
  <div class="child-item" data-id="2"> SomeContent </div>
  <div class="child-item" data-id="2"> SomeContent </div>
  <div class="child-item" data-id="3"> SomeContent </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If in DOM will exist another element with the same attribute to be removed first. I will use selector as ```document.querySelector(`.parent-div > [data-id='${dataID}']`);```

Comment: Usually something with the name of `id` is unique. If it doesn't, you can use querySelectorAll with the attribute selector, and then iterate and remove all of them.

Comment: Thanks, thats a better way!

Answer (score 0):

Use a simpler `querySelectorAll` call like so:

```
removeChild(id) {
    document.querySelectorAll(".parent-div .child-item").forEach(e => e.dataset.id == id ? e.remove() : 0);
}
```

Comment: Thanks your solution is great, one line codes always better, and it should be  "e.dataset.id == id" (for other ppl looking for answers)

Comment: Fixed @MiniMax.